# How can I use a SQL Server sp_* stored procedure/function in a if case?

Tags: sql-server

I'd like to check the catalog existence before I create or use it, so there is go.

```
sp_fulltext_catalog 'testcatelog1', 'create';

if not exists (select 1 from sys.sysfulltextcatalogs where name ='testcatelog1') 
  create fulltext catalog  testcatelog1;

if not exists (select 1 from sys.sysfulltextcatalogs where name ='testcatelog1') 
  sp_fulltext_catalog 'testcatelog1', 'create';
-- It doesn't work. Syntax error near 'sp_fulltext_catalog'.

if exists (select 1 from sys.sysfulltextcatalogs where name ='testcatelog2') 
  sp_fulltext_catalog 'testcatelog2', 'start_full';
-- It doesn't work. Syntax error near 'sp_fulltext_catalog'.
```

If SQL Server is designed that cann't run build-in function in T-SQL case, how to issuse an useful alternative statement?

Comment: what does `it doesn't work` means ? The command was not executed ? The command failed and returned an error ? The command returned no error but something else ?

Comment: @GuidoG My bad. There are syntax errors near 'sp_fulltext_catalog'.

Comment: You have to put an `EXEC ` before the function.

Comment: It's exact like @KekuSemau wrote, you cannot call a function by just calling its name, it should be `exec sp_fulltext_catalog 'testcatelog1', 'create'`

Comment: That isn't a *function* but a *stored procedure*. `EXEC` is optional only if the stored procedure call is the only statement in the batch.

Comment: @JeroenMostert of course, Microsoft even made the sp_ and fn_ prefixes, my bad.